# Lock-free SPMC queue

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, queue, lock-free

Here is my lock-free queue implementation for single producer with some preallocated memory. `T` is a simple type with no need for move operations. I don't use `bool pop(T& result)` in order to avoid double checking. I would love to see your feedback!

```
template <typename T>
class LockFreeQueue {
public:
    void setup(U8* buffer, U32 size) {
        m_buffer = (T*)buffer;
        m_size = size;
        clear();
    }

    void clear() {
        m_first.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        m_last.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

    void push(const T& value) {   // only for single producer
        U32 last = m_last.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        m_buffer[last] = value;
        U32 next = inc(last);
        ASSERT(next != m_first.load(std::memory_order_relaxed), "Queue overflow");
        m_last.store(next, std::memory_order_release);
    }

    bool isEmpty() {
        return m_first.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == m_last.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

    void pop(T& result) {    // for single consumer. check isEmpty() before
        ASSERT(!isEmpty(), "Queue is empty");
        U32 first = m_first.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        result = m_buffer[first];
        m_first.store(inc(first), std::memory_order_release);
    }

    bool tryPop(T& result) {    // for multiple consumers. don't use isEmpty()
        while (true) {
            U32 first = m_first.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
            if (first == m_last.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
                return false;
            result = m_buffer[first];
            if (m_first.compare_exchange_weak(first, inc(first), std::memory_order_release))
                return true;
        }
    }

private:
    U32 inc(U32 n) { return (n + 1) % m_size; }

    T* m_buffer;
    U32 m_size;
    std::atomic<U32> m_first;
    std::atomic<U32> m_last;
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Memory ordering problem

This line:

> ```
>         if (first == m_last.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
>             return false;
> ```

should be:

```
        if (first == m_last.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
            return false;
```

Otherwise, on the next line you may load the wrong value out of `m_buffer` due to the load being reordered before the load to `m_last`.  I spotted this because I noticed a `memory_order_release` without a corresponding `memory_order_acquire`.  The `pop()` function also needs a load of `m_last` with `memory_order_acquire`.

You have the same problem in `push()`.  If you don't load `m_first` with `memory_order_acquire`, you run the risk of writing to the buffer when it is full, thus overwriting some element.  Even the assertion won't help because you could have overwritten the buffer and then loaded a modified value for `m_first`.

#### Example of failure

Since your comment indicated that I didn't explain thoroughly enough, I will give an example of how the pop could go wrong.

1. The queue is empty, with `m_first = m_last = 0`.
2. The consumer calls `try_pop()`.
3. In `try_pop()`, `m_first` is loaded as 0.
4. **Now, the cpu speculatively loads `m_buffer[0]`, even though you haven't reached that line yet**.
5. The producer calls `push()`.
6. The producer writes `m_buffer[0]`, and then increments `m_last` to 1, in that order.
7. The consumer reads `m_last` as 1.
8. The consumer uses the value speculatively loaded in step 4 as the value for `m_buffer[0]`, but this value is wrong.

By adding the `memory_order_acquire`, you prevent the load of `m_buffer[0]` from happening until after step 7.

Comment: But `m_last.store(next, std::memory_order_release);` puts memory barrier on writes operations and we can't get new value from `m_buffer` before `m_last` would be published.

Comment: That only puts memory barriers on writes of the producer.  The consumer also needs barriers for its reads.

Comment: Shouldn't the `isEmpty` function also use `std::memory_order_acquire` instead of `std::memory_order_relaxed`? You don't know whether the producer or the consumer will call it.

Answer (score 3):

The management of the `m_buffer` is not tied to the lifetime of the queue.

The buffer is passed in as a char* buffer but the size along with it is in number of Ts it can hold. This can be confusing. Either pass in a T* directly with the number of Ts it can hold or pass the length of the buffer in bytes and then divide with sizeof(T) in the constructor;

```
void setup(T* buffer, U32 size) {
    m_buffer = buffer;
    m_size = size;
    clear();
}
```

There is no way for the producer to check if the queue is full. It will just overflow the buffer when asserts are disabled (which they will be in production).

```
bool isFull(){
    return inc(m_last.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) == m_first.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Since C++11 I generally prefer to stick to the standard types `uint32_t` and `uint8_t` etc. as defined in [`cstdint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). With custom typedefs like `U8` or `U32` you can never be sure that the correct type has been used unless you go and check the typedef.
2. Similar `ASSERT` seems to be a custom macros - I'd prefer to stick with the standard [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert).
3. I'd say `setup` is somewhat non-idiomatic C++. I would expect a constructor instead taking a buffer of type `T*`.